# Czechia or Czech Republic?

Tags: word-usage

I recently visited Czechia or did I visit the Czech Republic? If I visited the latter why did I not also visit the Slovak Republic instead of Slovakia?

Comment: If you visited the Czech Republic, I don't know why you didn't visit the Slovak Republic.  It was right next door.

Comment: The names of countries, like the names of anything in the universe, are idiosyncratic. *Czechia* hasn't gained currency in English. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_the_Czech_Republic for a quick overview.

Comment: +1 to @Choster's comment. I've heard of the term Czechia but have never heard anyone use it in practice, and it's interesting that even in the UN's list of member states ( http://www.un.org/en/members/ ) Czech Republic and Slovakia are used respectively. If I had to guess at the reason for this it would be that in English the name Czechia doesn't flow all that smoothly (IMHO anyway) with the repetition of two "hard sounding" (for want of a better term)  syllables one after the other. The name Slovakia has no such issues. But as I said, it's just a guess.

Comment: On your way there did you perhaps pass through Germany?  Or was it Deutschland?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the countries in the their respective languages are *Česká republika* and *Slovenská republika*.  The anglicized versioins are the Czech Republic and the Slovak Republic.

The official short-form of the *Česká republika* is *Česko*, anglicized to Czechia.

The short-form of *Slovenská republika* is *Slovensko*, anglicized to Slovakia.

Remember that you didn't visit a name; you visited a country.

Comment: It is just my guess, but wouldn't its former name (before separation) " Czechoslovakia" be the reason why the Chech Republic and Slovakia are their names?

Comment: @Rathony They got divorced in 1993 and, as often happens in a divorce, they took their original names.  I think the OP had a travel itinerary that read (in English) "Monday:Czech Republic, Friday:Slovakia" and he wants to know why the first name has the word *Republic* and the second one doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I think the same rule applies to China and Taiwan as we don't call China "the People's Republic of China" and Taiwan "the Republic of China". We just use popular/well-known names. +1)

Comment: @Rathony: No, the China / Taiwan thing is a VERY different situation and is something of a hornet's nest. Taiwan has been known to call itself the Republic of China but mainland China finds that offensive and insists that a term like Chinese Taipei is used. Mainland China insists that it is the legitimate government of Taiwan, Taiwan insists that it's the real China. On this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Taipei . Slovakia and the Czech Republic on the other hand are not belligerent to each other; they're more like an ex-couple that just don't want to sleep together any more.

Comment: @AlanK I should have put "the Republic of Singapore" or "the Republic of Korea" instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Czechia is the short name of the Czech Republic www.go-Czechia.com